# Android , what is best practice to create online data(JSON) transferring between multiple clients?

Tags: android, sockets, webserver

I know this question may seem broad , but I've been googling almost a month now .

I'm trying to build an application in Android , just like [QuizUp](https://www.quizup.com/) .

I'm new to android , but I've got many experience in web development .

**Question**  :

In application like quizup , there is a state that two user can play a very simple online game together (Simply asking some question simultaneously , and each user can see his/her opponent answers).

I know that I could use Sockets , but I don't know where to start ?

Is there a better solution ? maybe faster that sockets ?

Should I use something like Node.js for my Webserver or Apache will do ?

So far , I've created a webserver with Apache that serves the questions , but I don't know where to start for sending and receiving data ( in my case , Only JSON data ) between two opponent .

could someone give me a good tutorial or a hint , just where to start ?

Answer (score 2):

For your question you can try [Google realtime Multiplayer api](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer). They encapsulated all the communication for you in simple api protocol.

Comment: and for your link , this is exactly what I want , but using it , means that I should run my database (mongodb , or mysql ) on google ? 
I mean in my country , google api is blocked ! 
this will make any problem you think ?

Comment: And know my first comment has just been removed :P
this is completely crazy :D